# Core Data - merge objects with mutual value

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

For the simplicity of my question, this is my Core Data model (doesn't make perfect sense, only for the example):

```
Book  
-------  
- title  

- readers (to-many relationship to Reader)  


Reader  
------  
- name  

- book (to-one relationship to Book)
```

Currently a book with the same title can have multiple instances in db.
but I want to change that, I want to merge all the books with the same title to one instance (delete all the rest) and merge their readers.

For example, if my db looks like this:
1. Book title "A" readers: "1", "2", "3"
2. Book title "B" readers: "4", "5", "3", "7"
3. Book title "A" readers: "4", "1"

the new db will be:
1. Book title "A" readers: "1", "2", "3", "4"
2. Book title "B" readers: "4", "5", "3", "7"

as you can see, both books with title "A" where merge to one record including the readers.

So my question is how to do this effectively.
I'm thinking of some kind of query that will bring me all the books with more then one instance with the same title, and then maybe order them to groups according to the title.

Not sure if this is the right solution here,
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough time for a complete answer, but here is the pointer:

You can fetch duplicates with a fetch request of dictionary result type. You have to group it by title (property description) and add a count column (expression description). You can filter the result with a having argument, so you get the titles with count>1 only.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you keeping multiple instances of a book with same title. 
Even if two objects have the same contents they are still different.
Why don't you prefer adding readers to the already created book object.
But still if you want to merge the changes something you would want to do is

- First fetch all books with the same title like 'A' using a predicate
- Than seeing the first object as the one you want to merge in all other objects iterate over all the objects and add its readers but only those with a name that are not already present in the first one.
- delete all the book objects with title 'A' except the first one.

Now you would have only one object with a unique Book title having all the readers and the next time you have to add a reader

- Fetch the already created book instance from the store.
- Add the reader object in it.

`UPDATE`

- Get only the first Book object with a specific title
- Then query for all the readers in the store whose book title is the same and set there book object to this one.
- Delete all other Book objects with a specific title except the first u used.
- Remove multiple occurrences of readers in the book object.

Comment: this is just an example I invented to demonstrate the question. I'm looking for more efficient solution

Comment: @Mario I have updated the answer adding a little more efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch all the books. Then find the unique titles:

```
NSArray *uniqueBooks = [allBooks valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.title"];
```

Then loop over the uniqueBooks and for each book fetch all the matching entities. Convert the entities into an array and do another unique filtering.

```
NSArray *uniqueReader = [allReaders valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.name"];
```

Now you have a book and all the readers for that book insert them into a new store. When you are finished building the new store you can use that and delete the old one. You could also insert them into the same store but it would get complicated how to keep the new ones and delete the old ones and when deleting you would have to be careful with the delete behaviours and such.